# Add line break after every 60 characters in String for Java

Tags: java, regex, string

suppose the string is like this:

```
String msg = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

I want to add or append a line break (a carriage return) after every 60 characters either through looping or regEX (regEx would be much cooler).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like so in java :

```
String msg = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...";
String updatedMsg = msg.replaceAll("(.{60})", "$1\r");
```

This will replace every 60 characters with the same 60 characters and add a carriage return at the end.

The (.{60}) will capture a group of 60 characters. The $1 in the second will put the content of the group. The \r will be then appended to the 60 characters which have been just matched. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: Fine though the OP probably meant `\r\n`.

Comment: not working in my case.

Comment: have updated the code. please try. its working

Comment: nope...........